# How to check if an element inside a List of string array exists in another List of string array

Tags: c#, linq

I basically want to know if a string array from one list exists in another list of string array

So for example:
List 1:
{"A", "R1"}
{"A", "R2"}

List 2:
{"A", "R1"}
{"B", "R1"}
{"B", "R2"}

Then If I loop in List 1 to check whether it exists in List 2 the results will be:
true
false

I want to do it in LINQ if possilbe

Comment: Take a look at the `.Select()` and `.Contains()` functions.

Comment: what did you try yourself? You should post at least some own ideas.

Comment: what if list2 contained `{ "R1", "A" }` instead of `{ "A", "R1" }`? Does the order of the elements has any effect?

Comment: I have control over the order so it will always be the same

Comment: I tried using Exists() and Contains() but it always return false. Might be due to the fact that I am comparing arrays

Answer (score 3):

You can use

> Any and SequenceEqual

for this.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<string[]> testSet = new List<string[]>
{
    new string[] { "A", "R1" },
    new string[] { "A", "R2" }
};

List<string[]> resultSet = new List<string[]>
{
    new string[] { "A", "R1" },
    new string[] { "B", "R1" },
    new string[] { "B", "R2" }
};

// Checks if the value is found anywhere in the list
bool IsArrayInList(string[] value, List<string[]> list)
{
    return list.Any(value.SequenceEqual);
}

foreach (var val in testSet)
{
    Console.WriteLine(IsArrayInList(val,resultSet));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Worked like charm. I've always thought SequenceEqual was the key but can't seem to make it work. I've never thought of using it the way you did. Thank you very muhc

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a combination of [.Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0) and [.SequenceEqual()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-7.0) or [.All()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-7.0)

Example:

```
var list1 = new string[][]
{
    new string[] { "A", "R1" },
    new string[] { "A", "R2" },
};
var list2 = new string[][]
{
    new string[] { "A", "R1"},
    new string[] { "B", "R1"},
    new string[] { "B", "R2"},
};
var itemToFind = list1.First();
// Option 1
var isInList2 = list2.Any(i => i.SequenceEqual(itemToFind));
// Option 2
var isInList2Option2 = list2.Any(item => item.All(innerItem => itemToFind.Contains(innerItem)));
```

As-needed, you can improve these to account for ordering, case-insensitivity, exact number of arguments, etc...
Option 1 will find any matches where the inner sequence is in the same order, same-casing as what you are looking for.
Option 2 will find any matches where the inner sequence contains all of the values of the sequence you are checking for.

Hopefully this points you in the right direction at least.

Comment: Thank you for giving different approaches. i’ll try your suggestions